# Jquery .click() not working with livesearch

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, livesearch

I've implemented a live search basing on the string written in an input form.
Results are displayed correctly in this way:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_client" id="search_client" required autocomplete="off">
<ul id="results_client" class="liveresults">
    <li class="liveresult">
        <h5 class="result_name" data-value="Joo Fogn"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Joo Fogn</h5>
    </li>
    <li class="liveresult">
        <h5 class="result_name" data-value="Peter Nash"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Peter Nash</h5>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However I'd like to autocomplete the input with the showed result when a user click on one of the possible results.

To do it, I though to intercept the click on the result and give the result value to the input, as follows:

```
$(".result_name").click(function(){     
    $("#search_client").val($(".result_name").data("value"));
});
```

However when I click on a result, nothing happens. How can I fix it?

Comment: try $(this).data("value") because right now you are just finding any element with class result_name, either turn the class into an id or use this

Comment: is `result_name` coming dynamically?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can use `.on()` to bind click event and use `$(this)` to get clicked element jQuery instance to read its data value.

```
$(document).on("click",".result_name",function(){     
    //use $(this) to get clicked element and read its value
    $("#search_client").val($(this).data("value"));
});
```

Comment: `on()` is the way to go. Binding it like Bhushan says will also ensure binds will always work, even if the clicked element is generated later on (through Ajax, for example)

Answer (score 0):

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/g393kqgd/1/

```
$(".result_name").click(function(){   
    $("#search_client").val($(this).data("value"));
});
```